# pdo advanced search query building issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, advanced-search

I am trying to do an advanced search, i had this working but i was making full queries for each get variable, which was not good but it worked

now i am trying to build the query depending on if the url variable are empty. But i cant figure our why this is not working. The query works as i have tested this, am i not building the query correctly?

this is the function

```
public function search($man, $mod, $min, $max)
    {
        $this->currentLocation();
        $bind = '';

        $query .= 'SELECT listed_watches.*, watch.*, watch_images.* FROM listed_watches';

        $query .= 'LEFT JOIN watch ON watch.Id = listed_watches.watchID';

        $query .= 'LEFT JOIN watch_images ON listed_watches.url = watch_images.url';

        $query .= 'WHERE listed_watches.sellto REGEXP :search';

        if(!empty($man)){
            $query .= 'AND listed_watches.manufacture = :man';
            $bind  .= "$smt->bindValue(':man', $man);";
        }

        if(!empty($mod)){
            $query .= 'AND listed_watches.model = :mod';
            $bind  .= "$smt->bindValue(':mod', $mod);";
        }

        if(!empty($min)){
            $query .= 'AND listed_watches.minPrice > :min';
            $bind  .= "$smt->bindValue(':min', $min);";
        }

        if(!empty($max)){
            $query .= 'AND listed_watches.maxPrice < :max';
            $bind  .= "$smt->bindValue(':max', $max);";
        }

        $query .= 'GROUP BY listed_watches.id';

        $smt = $this->pdo->prepare(''.$query.'');

        $smt->bindValue(':search', "^[".$this->userLocation."]");
        $bind;
        return $smt->fetchAll();

    }
```

And when i search and enter choose a $man and $mon i get this error

```
Undefined variable: smt 
Trying to get property of non-object in
```

this error is refereeing to this line

```
$bind  .= "$smt->bindValue(':mod', $mod);";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need create $smt object, then you can use method on it.

```
    if(!empty($man)){
        $query .= 'AND listed_watches.manufacture = :man';
    }
    if(!empty($mod)){
        $query .= 'AND listed_watches.model = :mod';
    }

    // ...

    $query .= 'GROUP BY listed_watches.id';

    $smt = $this->pdo->prepare(''.$query.'');

    $smt->bindValue(':search', "^[".$this->userLocation."]");

    if(!empty($man)){
        $smt->bindValue(':man', $man);
    }
    if(!empty($mod)){
        $smt->bindValue(':mod', $mod);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but now im getting Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in -> this is pointing to the execute()

Comment: it is not possible if you do it correctly, check if you have this same number of :params_in_sql and bind params, add some "echo" in "if" if you dont see it